# How to unzip a '.zip' file uploaded to azure data lake store?

Tags: unzip, azure-data-lake

I have few zipped files uploaded in my ADLS folder. I want to unzip it. I do not have the access to download those files. Without unzipping, I cannot view the contents of the zipped file. How do I unzip the files.? I tried using ADF but its failing saying, 'unauthorized access'. I think I will have to use some custom code but I am unable to figure out.

Comment: is this a csv compressed file?

Comment: The zip file contains more than 1 csv file

Answer (score 2):

3 options to do it:

- Use datafactory to unzip the files using the copy file activity (native support for zip files).
- Create your own batch activity os azure batch and access the data lake and unzip the file
- Create a custom extractor that unzip the file and read and write line by line

Comment: Can you please explain more the first option ?

Comment: you can see here that you have support for zip files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview